# I/O Bound vs CPU Intensive

Tags: node.js

I read in the following tutorial -

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm

Node.js is a better choice for I/O bound applications only whereas it is not recommended for CPU intensive applications.

1. What is the difference between I/O bound vs CPU intensive?
2. Why Node.js is not a better choice for CPU intensive?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between I/O bound vs CPU intensive?

I/O bound means that a given task often waits for I/O. For example networking, file-io, and so on, are slow, compared to the CPU. When the CPU has to regularily wait for data to arrive, the task is said to be I/O bound.

CPU intensive is the opposite, when the CPU has to do a lot of work, computes data, without ever waiting for new data to arrive. It can just keep going.

> Why Node.js is not better choice for CPU intensive?

Node.js is slow compared to other choices, that makes it not so good for CPU-intensive tasks. Its asynchronous nature however makes it really good at I/O-bound tasks, as it can keep doing other work while it waits for the data to arrive asynchronously, something this is more difficult in other languages to achieve.

Comment: just adding - nodejs is nativelly single-threaded, so using only single thread to manage all events. There are frameworks enabling usage of multiple cores (e. g. cluster) but it I believe it still doesn't reach effectivity and maturity of others, nativelly multi-threaded platforms

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't that Node is slow, Node is quite fast, it's actually C++ under the hood. But the fact that it's single-threaded makes it slower than other languages that have multithreading embedded into them, like Java or Go. Node is better at IO-heavy applications than Java, for example, because Java threads' IO calls are blocking, while Node uses something called Event Loop to make non-blocking IO requests.